# Incorrect mutually exclusive types with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a object that I use to conditionally render some JSX. I want certain parts of the object to only be accessible after checks that confirm the existence of other properties. My use case:

```
const { alpha, bravo } = myObject;

if (alpha.loading === true) {
    // All properties on bravo must not exist here
  // this means
  // bravo.active must throw undefined error here
    return "Loading"
}

if (alpha.error === true) {
    return "Error"
}

// Bravo must be accessible here
// this means:
// type = {
//   signedIn: boolean  
//

if(bravo.signedIn === false {
   return "Guest"
}

return "Signed In"
```

Right now I'm using the following type for `myObject`:

```
type MyObjectType = {
    alpha: {
      loading: true;
    }
} | {
    alpha: {
      loading: false;
      error: true;
    }
} | {
    alpha: {
      loading: false;
      error: false;
    }
    bravo: {
      signedIn: false
    }
} | {
    alpha: {
      loading: false;
      error: false;
    }
    bravo: {
      signedIn: true;
      name: string;
    }
}
```

TypeScript errors with `Property 'signedIn' does not exist on type MyObjectType`. How can I destructure this property together with `auth` but not allow any properties on it before `auth.loading === false` and `auth.error == false`? The same goes for `bravo.name`, which must not exist until `bravo.signedIn === true`. Could anyone help me with this?

I really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That seems like the wrong approach, it is really convoluted.

Comment: I just updated the question to fix some mistakes, could you tell me why you think it's convoluted and what would be a better approach? I want to avoid having to check for each property whether it is defined. I know only these exact cases in my type will ever exist.

Comment: Where is `bravo.active` coming from? None of your types have it stated.

Comment: Sorry, I quickly copy pasted this code! I'll fix it right now! It can be ignored

Comment: @JensM: You are trying to create some kind of state machine via the type system. I do not know how exactly i would approach this, but i would not write code like that.

Comment: What is `user`? What is `auth`? The error message doesn’t seem to come from any code you’ve presented.  Please consider modifying the code here to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE so that others can demonstrate the issue for themselves before answering.

Comment: @jcalz should be fixed. I changed the variable names from a real world case to make it more clear but I forgot to change some. Please forgive me.

Comment: @H.B. I agree. Perhaps a states table or other implementation of a state machine is enough. That should restrict which code runs when and not allow a wrong state transition or executing code that doesn't make sense. So, basically defining what each state should contain as boolean flags and leaving them `type alpha = {loading: boolean, error: boolean}` should be enough. The state machine implementation itself will ensure the correctness.

Comment: If I move `bravo` to inside `alpha` as a property, the types do prevent me from accessing it until `auth.loading === false and auth.error == false`. It's just that I can't destructure the property from `myObject`. I would have to add `bravo` to the `loading` type and the `error: true` type as a object with no properties, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I ended up "solving" this by using type predicates

Comment: While the approach might not be totally suitable for solving this particular problem, I still find this an interesting question. I would have thought you could declare a joint type like `type Step1 = {alpha: {error: true}, beta: never}` and `type Step2= {alpha: {error: false}, beta: {data: string}}` for example. Then do your `obj = Step1 | Step2`. However, when that's done the relationship between the two is lost - `alpha` is a `{error: true} | {error: false}` while `beta` is assumed to just be `{data: string}`, so the type system just ignores the possibility of `never`

Comment: @VLAZ, yeah, I don't understand why TypeScript does this. It allows this "type narrowing" that I'm doing within a single object but not across 2 objects that are properties of a larger object. Super strange, but I agree that my agree was not too smart. I ended up moving all properties from alpha into the parent object, and now it works great. I thought TypeScript would solve many of JavaScript's inconsistencies, but recently I've been quite dissapointed in TypeScript because of many little inconsistencies like this one.

Comment: @JensM it's really bizarre. Destructuring also destroys the relationship here. I'm drafting an answer but it's really what you already observed, mostly for the benefit of others. I really hope somebody comes in with a better solution.

Comment: Also, the error "Object may only specify known properties" is super inconsistent! Thanks for all your research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could figure out how to make related properties work is by keeping `myObject` as a *single* flat object with flags on it. The types are then the following:

```
type State1 = {
    loading: true;
}

type State2 = {
    loading: false;
    error: true;
}

type State3 = {
    loading: false;
    error: false;
    signedIn: false;
}

type State4 = {
    loading: false;
    error: false;
    signedIn: true;
    name: string;
}

type MyObjectType = State1 | State2 | State3 | State4;
```

Note, these are generic names as I'm trying to address the generic problem of relations between values. Quick side note - this could really be improved by naming the types better: `type PageState = Loading | Error | Unsigned | LoggedIn` However, I will use the generic names.

With these types it is possible to define relationshits such that knowing which of the states you are in and which you are not in by utilising type narrowing. Here is a descriptive example:

```
if (myObject.loading === true) {
    /* Only State1 inside the if */

    console.log(myObject.name);     //error - we are in State1 - no such property
    console.log(myObject.signedIn); //error - we are in State1 - no such property
    console.log(myObject.error);    //error - we are in State1 - no such property

    return "Loading"
}
/* We've filtered State1. Below `myObject` can only be State2 | State3 | State4 */

if (myObject.error === true) {
    /* Only State2 inside the if */

    if (myObject.loading === true) { //error - `loading` will never be `true` in State2
        console.log("hello")
    }
    console.log(myObject.name);      //error - we are in State2 - no such property
    console.log(myObject.signedIn);  //error - we are in State2 - no such property

    return "Error"
}
/* We've filtered State2. Below `myObject` can only be State3 | State4 */

if (myObject.loading === true) { //error - `loading` will never be `true` in State3 or State4
    console.log("hello")
}

if (myObject.error === true) {   //error - `error` will never be `true` in State3 or State4
    console.log("hello")
}

console.log(myObject.signedIn);  //correct - `signedIn` exists in State3 and State4
console.log(myObject.name);      //error - `name` only exists in State4, not in State3. We could be in either

if (myObject.signedIn === false) {
    /* Only State3 inside the if */

    if (myObject.loading === true) { //error - `loading` will never be `true` in State4
        console.log("hello")
    }
    if (myObject.error === true) {   //error - `error` will never be `true` State4
        console.log("hello")
    }

    return "Guest"
}
/* We've filtered State3. Below `myObject` can only be State4 */

if (myObject.loading === true) {   //error - `loading` will never be `true` in State4
    console.log("hello")
}

if (myObject.error === true) {     //error - `error` will never be `true` in State3 or State4
    console.log("hello")
}

if (myObject.signedIn === false) { //error - `signedIn` will never be `false` in State4
    console.log("hello")
}

return "Signed In"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwIEYoF4oG8CwAoAkADYD28AJgJYB2A5gFxTABOArhANx4C+eeoksBEgBM6LHiKlKtBgDN4hAM4cJEJk2JMGzNp1w9cfcNDiIIAZjE4CJctXpR5SlQTUatjhcr35FFGlQQZACSVHJeLgZGAqZIACxWErbSDk7equqa4c4+fgFBodqsLvhU8AC2EAyKzPZ6Ubj80ACyIADyAEYAVhAAxsAAKsZisShQAD6CZqKTo5azQhBxvLiyLFT9FMRUUGTEMMSVwAAW9gAU5e3dfcAMrZ09-UOQAJTiBBSyUBdXj8AAdMl7Og0BgdBA3tZ8PgAPQAKigbSohBAUyQqGofjI0BO0E+UDhMJW0N620UxEIEEBxBoPweN3+ZUqL3YUDZbJhMLcmigAFooAB3aDwJh4najVD8qjEKCKFi9Y5QMAaSBMUASfCkqjkynU2mXen9f55QIhKgsqCc7lMPmC4WiqDUNFjKUyuUKpUqtTqgiaskUqkkfW-BnWi3sq2ZG38oVQEVi52SqDS2XyxXK4iqn0a0XAFhMHYAIgAMlJ7IWJAZYQiAOoQADkADdoLIKIQkKKyIn-lAAEIQEgCqAAAwN136w6gvXgO22KKgHRMixmzvmzoShOJ+Lp44B1pBYOKkI18MRyNRo1EmIo2MYxzxX03hl927Hf2pdloB8YR6wlq5Ua2sOQK0JOAptoQyYQM2NqLiO4KTk6l4an62oBnqZyFvehAkIWLwalWqE6oGNI7u+TIQqy7IcgB7i2rG8aOuKy62im7rpl6aogBqWrERhb4MiaBTmlRkZ0TG9oJperFummnqZt63HPtCub5kWACiUYVgQVannWTYtm2HZBM6wg9v2g4jgJE5TjOUBzqicFzBM64EkSymviGRogTQ37gpC-77vywFlqBgoQVBMELtAw4IUxq72TaozLL6vHoUGmHYbh+E6VuXxkaGgGgoebABTRQUjtaYERYEUVwbFxSIcxZiWDyyU8f6uoZVhA7ZZWxJpV1pHWQCQlmuGnKkuoNxAWNoSThAAAeFA1Io8XOTOXbtQQg0kcGhoAhR4bUWJPLBRRk4OVAS0rcAa1IYscQADTJsQwDrYs5g9nWU7ECwhBdnBToQBQuJMHl3wjca-imqE35pBC7zQqeSLzs5163rijqPu5GqeQdH4pH5v6YIFgHBT51U4ZFajRfBjUfWYKXQkR6WkT1OHEHhBF4-lUP7sVP6lX+5Xk5VUZU5BtW0-VcXbSzu0YRzfW+g0KkQHmBZQIWADibA1Np+C6bWDbNo4RlqCZczmQOxBDqOXnAJO06zuedPJW5EMFd5oW+YL-ki2T4kjpT4XU9LsExXFD1Mx1aFDbSytczlRte-zRWgkLiOkydtFneL7iSzTkf02wTUJW1j1x3x3VZcn-UeXzjvQ-kZrwxEAWndGI5zVQRcR3Tw4I+X8uswnmW9fXuXKapWuFjAMMmaE2lcEAA)

This is only possible if directly accessing the properties from `myObject` here.

Destructuring cannot be used, unfortunately. The first problem is doing:

```
const { loading, error, signedIn, name } = myObject;
```

in the beginning does not work because `myObject` is still of type `State1 | State2 | State3 | State4` and `error`, `signedIn`, `name` do not exist on all four types.

The next issue is that TypeScript does not seem to follow the types through destructuring. If it did, this should have work:

```
const { loading } = myObject;

if (loading === true) //filter State1
    return "Loading"

const { error } = myObject;

if (error === true) //filter State2
    return "Error"

const { signedIn } = myObject;

if (signedIn === false) //filter State3
    return "Guest"

const { name } = myObject;

return "Signed In"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwIEYoF4oG8CwAoAkADYD28AJgJYB2A5gFxTABOArhANx4C+eeoksBEgBM6LHiKlKtBgDN4hAM4cJEJk2JMGzNp1w9cfcNDiIIAZjE4CJctXpR5SlQTUatjhcr35FFGlQQZACSVHJeLgZGAqZIACxWErbSDk7equqa4c4+fgFBodqsLvhU8AC2EAyKzPZ6Ubj80ACyIADyAEYAVhAAxsAAKsZisShQAD6CZqKTo5azQhBxvLiyLFT9FMRUUGTEMMSVwAAW9gAU5e3dfcAMrZ09-UOQAJTiBL3bNVhQyfZQXDElweNz0EgosigZz+tHQaAwOggbwA9MjZBRCEgmFMkMgJPgmBBgCwmDsAEQAGSk9jJK3wnyo30wUDcmgBQKuj2AYIIEKhrOx8IRxRRaIxWJxEGE+MJxNJUDJAFFMkxaYYPl9gD88oEQjtARhgdd+jz8HyzjqCjshZ5nKL0Zi1JLzDKiSTyQBxNg1NUSBlMqBlSrsw2c0F02XuhUwfy6qChNVcIA)

However, the TypeScript compiler does not determine that after `if (loading === true) return "Loading"` the variable `myObject` cannot be `State1`. It's still treated as a `State1 | State2 | State3 | State4` because no type narrowing is being performed.

---

I tried your original approach as well. Here is a simplified version:

```
type StateA = {
    alpha: { error: "not logged in"; },
    bravo: never
}

type StateB = {
    alpha: { error: "not premium"; },
    bravo: never
}

type StateC = {
    alpha: { error: false; },
    bravo: { data: string }
}

type MyObjectType = StateA | StateB | StateC
```

It's down to three states for some brevity.

The first problem is that if `bravo` is not present in all different states, then TypeScript will always say it's not there. This becomes interesting later on<sup>See "Let's come back" below</sup>. For now, my solution was to add `bravo: never` in every state where there *shouldn't* be a `bravo` option.

The next problem is that TypeScript does not seem to consider `myObject.alpha` and `myObject.bravo` to be connected. According to the compiler `alpha` is of type `{ error: "not logged in"; } | { error: "not premium"; } | { error: false; }` while `bravo` is of type `{ data: string; }`

```
if (myObject.alpha.error === "not logged in") {
    console.log(myObject.bravo.data) //should be an error but isn't
    return "Please log in"
}

console.log(myObject.bravo.data)     //should be an error but isn't

//error - type if `myObject.alpha` is narrowed to: { error: "not premium"; } | { error: false; }
if (myObject.alpha.error === "not logged in") { }

if (myObject.alpha.error === "not premium") {
    console.log(myObject.bravo.data) //should be an error but isn't
    return "Please pay"
}

//error - type if `myObject.alpha` is narrowed to:{ error: false; }
if (myObject.alpha.error === "not premium") { }

console.log(myObject.bravo.data)     //should only work here

return "Signed In"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwIEEoF4oG8CwAoAkPADZgAW8AXFlBAE60D2tVARAHYPBREMDmvEACZQAlmxYBuKAF8ANHnwAjWvABuDKmwiq6eaXjyhIsBEgBC6LAuJlK1Oo2ZR2nKGFoQAtiICunyTLyBMpqGlBaOrR6BrhG0HCIEADCljgENuRUmDT0TFQAZsQAzhBScgoh6llQgoh2RcC0Yrwy0biG4NAAsiAA8ooAVhAAxsAAKp2WCUioAD4miRbz08kx+T5soyIMbDUMMAyeEMCkzQAUnn2DI8BUPf1DoxOQAJRWBCL5UBdXj8AAdBl4P8HEx0GgMC4uDx+EJROI3ml8PhhjsigwiBB-jCfg8bv9Kgx-rUEG8APRkoqkBg+IjCRTQeC7UG0KCKHxcERFNgAcmACnwHmAPlouxYAAVMfAStw+PCWAp9O0CKi2OjMdi+LjrqMCSp1MS6m8oCaoBSqTS6WzGczcqz2ZzuXyYvgKSyoABaKBxURfAAGlzxuqBftERXC8FyAHc4cAwtkWawOFx3F5fP4ylB5gm7QViqVWh8vtq-oCSOQQXbwZDk7LYcIxCxEYWFJ9voGdQCgZXHNXnLXU94-E33sjVeqsTiO6XCYbSWbKdTafSbTlew6w7z+QRBccRWLJRBpdAwPAQAqCEqFG6q16fW2A798SGwxHo7GNDnHHmiCUyq3i2nZ9y2Bd0IRrVxB3TEdsivFU0QxSctSA3VZxJeBjVNc0lytHYiBAKAoyYABrKBSDoCAXSFfdnBgEReC0YQAElxD0IA)

So, TypeScript tracks the types of these two properties independently. It never throws an error for accessing `myObject.bravo` even when you shouldn't be able to because in `StateA` the property `bravo` should be `never`. The type of `alpha` *is* correctly narrowed, however. After the first `if` you are not allowed to check for `"not logged in"` because the type *for* `alpha` which is *from* `StateA` is filtered out.

**Let's come back** to why the absence of `bravo` is interesting. If `bravo` was *not* included in `StateA` and `StateB`, then you would instead get an error in the final log statement where it says `//should only work here`. The compiler error explicitly states

> Property 'bravo' does not exist on type 'StateA'

If instead the states were defined as:

```
type StateA = {
    alpha: { error: "not logged in"; },
    bravo: null
}

type StateB = {
    alpha: { error: "not premium"; },
    bravo: null
}

type StateC = {
    alpha: { error: false; },
    bravo: { data: string }
}
```

It's still not good, since `myObject.bravo` is simply determined to be `bravo: { data: string; } | null` and each log location that tries to access `myObject.bravo.data` throws a compiler error as it *might* be `null`. Its type is still not narrowed in tandem with `myObject.alpha`: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=25&pln=13&pc=9#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-KOQpF4ogkugYHgIDlBAVChdFY9Xpbfp+eKDIbDkejGizThzRGKpWbhcnj6lkCrrglWbj9qmQ5ZBeSqoui44agB2rTsS8CGsapoLhaUDbEQIBQBGTAANZQKQdAQE6Aq7i4MAiLwbCwgAkuI+hAA)

---

As a last quick note, I also tried to define the states as tuples to see if they are treated any differently:

```
type StateA = [
    { error: "not logged in"; },
    never
]

type StateB = [
    { error: "not premium"; },
    never
]

type StateC = [
    { error: false; },
    { data: string }
]
```

However, the very same behaviour occurs. Each one the two items in the tuple are independent of each other but type narrowing does work for the first item (formerly named `alpha`): [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwIEEoF4oG0CwAoAkAN5QQBOpA9qQFxQBEAdhcFADYUDmHEAJlAJYM6AbigBfADR58DCADcyeALp48oSLARIAQuizTiZSjXpMWYUhAC2-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)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for this investigation work. I'll mark this as solved.

Comment: @JensM I guess I just confirmed what you already knew. I'd love to actually know if I'm doing something wrong here and there *is* a way to link two types together like you proposed. Destructuring does destroy that link and I can see why. I think it's probably a lot harder to track variables that are disassociated from the object (e.g., `a = obj.a; b = obj.b`). However, TS does not seem to be considering "the whole package" (`obj`) anyway. Yet it *does* track possibilities for both `obj.a` and `obj.b` separately. I find it strange. I'd personally love a more in-depth explanation.