# Dealing with default values with destructuring and discriminated union

Tags: typescript

I know similar questions have been asked before but I wanted to confirm my solution and look for best practices.

Let's say I have code like below where I would like my function to accept two scenarios.

```
type HeaderPropsBase = {
    name: string
}

type HeaderProps = HeaderPropsBase & ({
    sortable: true
    sortValue: string
} | {
    sortable?: false
    sortValue?: never
})

function Header(props: HeaderProps) {
    const { sortable = false, sortValue, name } = props
    if (sortable) {
        return sortValue.length // error, sortValue is possibly undefined
    } else {
        return name.length
    }
}
```

Because I would like to have `sortable` optional but still have the logic, I am setting it as `false` by default.
However typescript cannot infere `sortValue` in that case and if I understand correctly this is due to destructuring. If I change the `if` part to

```
if (props.sortable) {
  return props.sortValue.length
}
```

error goes away.

How do people deal with this? <strike>I can think of a ways, e.g.</strike>

```
const { sortable, sortValue, name } = {...props, sortable: props.sortable ?? false }
```

but this is ugly and would confuse people without some comment.

EDIT: This actualy does not work, I guess the only way is to avoid destructuring

Comment: I think people deal with it by not destructuring. There's no shame in using `props.`; I'm not sure where people are picking up this idea.

Comment: @HereticMonkey ok and what about default values then?

Comment: `props.sortable = props.sortable ?? false;`

Comment: sure, of course me using props was no coincidence - my example in reality is using react where props are immutable so I guess something like my example with create a copy of props would work - or in general case adding some function that would fill the missing values. 
Anyway, I understand the limitation but it's a shame it breaks what I think is idiomatic way of doing things in Javascript/React

Comment: You can see something similar here: [Incorrect mutually exclusive types with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62574795). Destructuring destroys the relationship between the values - the compiler can track that `{sortable: true, sortValue: "abc"}` does have both properties, but doing `{sortable, sortValue} = obj` breaks that and the compiler considers them as completely separate values.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks, yeah I think I understand, I was just looking for ways to deal with that.

Comment: This was actually very helpful for my case because TS doesn't understand the optional discriminated union really well. Setting the mutually exclusive prop (in this case, `sortValue`) to `never` solved it for me when `sortable === false` or `undefined`. Otherwise TypeScript would say it's fine to set `sortValue` even if I didn't pass in the `sortable` prop. So thanks for posting this!